# Is CrudRepository.save(Iterable<S>) is atomic?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am saving multiple objects using `CrudRepository.save(Iterable<S>)`.

is this operation behaviour is atomic?

What will happen if I save 10 entities and it fails for 6th one?

Comment: IIRC all methods from `CrudRepository` will get the `@Transactional` annotation by default, thus a failure will not persist anything to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the seen this is what's happening in case of `SimpleJpaRepository` save method with Iterable

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> More save(Iterable<S> entities) {

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

It's worth noting that save with `Iterable` has changed to `saveAll` in latest versions
[Refer changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commit/b49d7662d94dc9a05b9993f8645c8163f4799373#diff-0781e000cdc895cb9d16c9d5bbd85f32) for more detail

> What will happen if I save 10 entities and it fails for 6th one?

By default `CrudRespository` will have `@Transactional` so on case of exception nothing is saved.

In case of handling manually this will work

If you are doing something like this things will be rollback.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class)
public List<Car> saveAllOrNone(List<Car> cars) {
    for(Car car: cars) {
        repo.save(car);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-) that's how saveAll looks like:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)
```

But, to be sure it will work as single atomic transaction you need:

1) Ensure transactions support work for you

2) Ensure autocommit is set to false (optional, in case if will not work)

Comment: Spring disables autocommit for @Transactional methods (when such method is executed and reverts to a previous setting after completion), therefore point 2 is not necessary

Comment: @Lesiak previously I got trouble with autocomit=true + Spring Boot 1.5 + MariaDB. Actually it was not working as a single atomic transaction before I sen autocommit + default autocommit to false. Add optional label to #2, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is atomic. `SimpleJpaRepository` is the default implementation for the interface `CrudRepository`. The `save` method is annotated with `Transactional` at the implementation. So in case of any error, everything will be rolled back.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
    List<S> result = new ArrayList();
    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    } else {
        Iterator var3 = entities.iterator();

        while(var3.hasNext()) {
            S entity = var3.next();
            result.add(this.save(entity));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: *What will happen if I save 10 entities and it fails for 6th one?* and you answer with "Yes"?

Comment: @Eugene I believe he meant: `Yes, it is atomic`. What's wrong with that ?

Comment: @NiVeR nothing wrong _if he meant that_... and a proper edit would be needed in such a case

Comment: Eugene and NiveR, Thanks for the feedback. I edited my answer.